# Using Plone 4 and pas.plugins.sqlalchemy with many users

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlalchemy, plone, zope

I've been using **pas.plugins.sqlalchemy** to provide an RDBMS backend for authentication and memberdata storage, using MySQL. Authentication works perfectly and member data is correctly stored and retrived on the RDBMS. The current users are over **20.000**

However, user enumeration takes ages. I have checked the "**Many users**" in the *Plone Control Panel / Users and Groups section* but even a simple user search takes a near infinite amount of time. By debugging the **plugin.py** script I noticed that **enumerateUsers()** is called as many times as the number of users stored; therefore, an enormous amount of CPU time is needed to complete a simple search request, as the query is matched against each username, one user at a time, one *query* at a time.

Am I missing something here? Isn't pas.plugins.sqlalchemy useful especially when you have a very large number users? Currently, I have the sql plugin as top priority in my *acl_users/plugins/User Enumeration* setup. Should I change this?

Comment: Is there no caching implemented? Usually you can associate the stuff with a RAMCacheManager or implement caching (e.g. through plone.memoize) on the plugin level which will usually help _a lot_.

Comment: @Sentinel No, there's no caching implemented on the plugin level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've pretty much inherited maintenance pas.plugins.sqlalchemy - but I haven't personally used it for more than a handful of users, yet.  If you file a bug at https://github.com/auspex/pas.plugins.sqlalchemy/issues, I'll see what I can do.

I don't think it can make much difference what order the enumeration occurs - it still has to enumerate all the users in the SQL db.  So it either does them before the ones found in the ZODB, or after.  It *sounds* as if the problem begins with Zope - calling enumerateUsers() once per user seems excessive - but even so, it shouldn't be necessary to make a request to the relational db per enumeration.

Comment: I'm guessing this changed in Plone 4 because the users and groups control panel now tries to show the fullname for each user...which entails a property lookup that triggers the extra enumerateUsers calls.

Comment: The precise point where it stalls is plone/app/controlpanel/usergroups.py:168